# Woocommerce - Trying to get variable product quantity sum in admin

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

as in title, i'm trying to get sum of my variable product (for each product) in admin instead of 'out-of-stock' or 'in-stock' indication. I've variable product so i need sum of one variation to get all my product (ive a pant in different size and different colour but i need only sum of all size). Anyone got this before me?
Thanks in advance, Francesco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found solution.
First of all added this

```
function add_qty_admin( $column ) {
        if (!isset($columns['total_qty']))
        $columns['total_qty'] = "Quantità";
        return $columns;
    }
add_filter( 'manage_posts_columns', 'add_qty_admin' );
```

to functions.php in order to have a column in my backend.

Then i've added also this

```
function admin_post_data_row($column_name, $post_id)
{
    global $wpdb;
    switch($column_name)
    {
        case 'total_qty':
            $query = "SELECT sum(meta_value)
                      FROM $wpdb->posts AS p, $wpdb->postmeta AS s
                      WHERE p.post_parent = %d
                      AND p.post_type = 'product_variation'
                      AND p.post_status = 'publish'
                      AND p.id = s.post_id
                      AND s.meta_key = '_stock'";

            $product_qty = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare($query,$post_id));
            if ($product_qty) echo $product_qty;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column', 'admin_post_data_row', 10, 2);
```

where `$query` is SQL query that sum all `_stock` value in `postmeta` table for `post_parent` posts that are the variations of `post_id`.

Sorry for my poor english (i'm italian), i hope this code can be helpful fot other people.
Francesco.