# Woocommerce - Variable product and standard product quantity totals in admin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product

I'm trying to create a column in the admin products page that will show the total product amounts for variable and standard products.
I'd also like it to be sortable if possible.

I found Francesco Di Candia's solution for showing the total stock quantity of a variable product "[Woocommerce - Trying to get variable product quantity sum in admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19419093/woocommerce-trying-to-get-variable-product-quantity-sum-in-admin)"

```
function add_qty_admin( $column ) {
    if (!isset($columns['total_qty']))
    $columns['total_qty'] = "Total Stock";
    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_posts_columns', 'add_qty_admin' );

function admin_post_data_row($column_name, $post_id)
{
    global $wpdb;
    switch($column_name)
    {
        case 'total_qty':
            $query = "SELECT sum(meta_value)
                      FROM $wpdb->posts AS p, $wpdb->postmeta AS s
                      WHERE p.post_parent = %d
                      AND p.post_type = 'product_variation'
                      AND p.post_status = 'publish'
                      AND p.id = s.post_id
                      AND s.meta_key = '_stock'";

        $product_qty = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare($query,$post_id));
        if ($product_qty) echo $product_qty;
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
}
add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column', 'admin_post_data_row', 10, 2);
```

However if the product isn't a variable product the area is left blank.

Is there a way to make the column display the variable stock or the standard stock amounts using the 'is_in_stock' hook from the default stock column if it's not a variable product?

And finally if this can be done would there be a way to make the column sortable?

Thanks for your help!

Kind regards,
JP

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit more? 

1. What Do you want display? a. Total sum : For  Simple Product sum(quantity*price) and For Variable Product - sum(variation quantities*Variation price each respectively) or b. Total Stock Count : For Simple Product (Quantity) and Variable Product sum(Variation Quantity).
 2. If you want a option then whether you want sum of sale prices or regular prices.? What do you want in a situation for Variable products were some variations are on sale and some are not. In that case how do you need the total to be calculated?

Comment: Hi WisdmLabs,
I completely missed your response and gave up haha!
It's only now that I've decided to give it another attempt that I've seen your question, sorry for the delay getting back to you :)

What I'm trying to display is just the stock amounts, the code above displays the total quantity for variable products. Which is great.
I'd also like to show the total quantity of simple products in the same column and have the column sortable.

Comment: So at the moment if I have a variable product with 3 different variations 1 with 3 in stock, 1 with 5 in stock and 1 with 4 in stock the total stock count is 12... perfect.
However the column only shows the total stock for variable products.
Can I add an addition 'case' that will show the simple product stock amounts in the same column do you think?
Any insight you might have would be very much appreciated :)
Kind regards,
JP